How to upload images to Cloudflare Images using an Expo App
I am using Axios and React Native Expo. I am getting the image from the user using the expo-image-picker library. I want to get images from my users and upload them to Cloudflare images how can I do that? I have also tried uploading Digital Ocean Spaces but that too gives similar errors. I want a image hosting service that works with my expo app. Cloudinairy is very expensive.
I have tried the official docs but am running into errors, here is the code I used-
import { View, Text, TextInput, Alert, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import * as Icon from 'react-native-feather';
import { themeColors } from '../theme';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import axios from 'axios';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto';
import { ReadableStream } from 'web-streams-polyfill';
globalThis.ReadableStream = ReadableStream;

// Replace these with your actual Cloudflare account details
const CLOUDFLARE_ACCOUNT_ID = '';
const CLOUDFLARE_API_TOKEN = '';

export default function AddItems({ navigation }) {
  const [produceName, setProduceName] = useState('');
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState('');
  const [price, setPrice] = useState('');
  const [itemImage, setItemImage] = useState('');
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadPhoneNumber = async () => {
      try {
        const storedPhoneNumber = await AsyncStorage.getItem('phone');
        if (storedPhoneNumber) {
          setPhoneNumber(storedPhoneNumber);
        } else {
          Alert.alert('Error', 'Phone number not found');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error loading phone number from AsyncStorage:', error);
      }
    };

    loadPhoneNumber();
  }, []);

  const pickImageAsync = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      uploadImage(result.assets[0]);
    } else {
      alert('You did not select any image.');
    }
  };

  const getImageBlob = async (uri) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    return blob;
  };
  
  const uploadImage = async (imageAsset) => {
    setUploading(true);
    const customPath = `${uuidv4()}-${produceName.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()}`;
  
    try {
      const blob = await getImageBlob(imageAsset.uri);
  
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', blob, 'image.jpg');
      formData.append('id', customPath);
  
      console.log('Uploading to Cloudflare...');
      console.log('FormData:', JSON.stringify(formData));
      
      const response = await axios.post(
        `https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/${CLOUDFLARE_ACCOUNT_ID}/images/v1`,
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${CLOUDFLARE_API_TOKEN}`,
          },
          timeout: 30000, // Increased timeout to 30 seconds
        }
      );
  
      console.log('Cloudflare response:', response.data);
  
      if (response.data.success) {
        const imageUrl = response.data.result.variants[0];
        setItemImage(imageUrl);
        Alert.alert('Success', 'Image uploaded successfully');
      } else {
        throw new Error('Upload failed: ' + JSON.stringify(response.data.errors));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
      if (error.response) {
        console.error('Error data:', error.response.data);
        console.error('Error status:', error.response.status);
        console.error('Error headers:', error.response.headers);
      } else if (error.request) {
        console.error('Error request:', error.request);
      } else {
        console.error('Error message:', error.message);
      }
      Alert.alert('Error', `Failed to upload image: ${error.message}`);
    } finally {
      setUploading(false);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    if (!produceName || !quantity || !price) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'All fields are required');
      return;
    }

    try {
      const formData = {
        phoneNumber,
        itemName: produceName,
        quantity,
        price,
        itemImage,
      };

      const response = await axios.post(
        'myurl/api/supplier/add-item',
        formData
      );

      if (response.status === 200) {
        Alert.alert('Success', 'Item added successfully!');
        navigation.goBack();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error adding item:', error.response?.data || error.message);
      Alert.alert(
        'Error',
        error.response?.data?.message || 'Failed to add item, please try again'
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    //frontend code
  );
}

